# Babel 6 presets specified in .babelrc not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

as the title suggests, basically according to the docs, with the new Babel 6 we are now supposed to pass in plugins/presets since by default it would not do anything with our code.

So I created a .babelrc file in my project directory with the following (just like in the docs)

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

However this would not work.
Since I'm using webpack and babel-loader, I came across a different answer that suggested to put something like this in the webpack config:

```
{
     test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel", query: {
         presets: ["es2015"]
     }
}
```

And this works. 
So my question is whether this is a bug in the new Babel or there is something obviously wrong that I'm missing? I used to use Babel 5 and Webpack, and I was able to specify the babel config in .babelrc no problem...

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The problem only occurred when running the eslint loader before the babel loader. However just updated to latest babel-loader 6.2.0 and everything is working again.

```
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "eslint"}
        ],
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel"},
            { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "style!css!postcss"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with `babel-loader`. It should be fixed in release [6.1.0](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/releases/tag/v6.1.0).

You can see the [release/v6.1.0](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/commit/37bab5244e3b326759c04bcdbdd758fb7aefd866) summary:

```
 * release/v6.1.0:
 Update CHANGELOG.md and package.json
 Set source file name relative to options.sourceRoot
 Allow babelrc to be specified for cache purposes
 Add BABEL_ENV || NODE_ENV to default cacheIdentifier
```

So updating babel-loader will suffice.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated to 6.1.0, however the problem persists with the same 'Unexpected Token' error. (Putting the presets back in webpack config still works as expected)

Comment: @luanped Are you using any other loader apart from `babel`? Could you post your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Hi @dreyescat, added the config file in the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @luanped What I suspected :). I haven't figured out why yet... but I don't know why introducing `eslint` to the mix causes this error. Just remove the `eslint-loader` and you will see it works with `.babelrc`. I am not proposing this as a solution but just to point out from where could the issue come from.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dreyescat, indeed this would make it work. So do you know if this is a bug with Babel or Webpack? Thanks again

Comment: @luanped Not sure... but I would bet for a Babel related issue. It is the one that has done a major release recently.